# Import a Swift module in Obj C module

Tags: ios, swift, module, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have a xcworkspace with two xcodeprojects inside (one is a static library where all the base functionalities are implemented and the other is a demo project which uses classes from first one) - and all the code so far has been written in Objective C. What I want to achieve is create a Swift class in the static library and then access it from an Objective C class in the 'demo' xcodeproj.

I have created this 'Test.swift' class and a bridging header that was created automatically (changed the Defines Module property to YES in the Build setting), and everything works well - I can access it from Obj C classes in the same project. Next, I am creating a new "DemoTest.swift" Swift class in the 'demo' project and subclassing the Test.swift (which works). However, when trying to access this class from an Objective C file in the 'demo' project, the compiler doesn't recognize my "base" module  -

```
In file included from 
xxxxx/AppDelegate.m:26:
xxxxx/mpdemo-Swift.h:189:9: fatal error: module 'mpbba' not found
@import mpbba;
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~
1 error generated.
```

My question is how can I have a Swift code imported into another Objective C module?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what to do:**

1. configure an Objective-C **bridging header**
2. Click on your Xcode Project file
3. Click on **Build Settings**
4. Find the Search bar and search for **Defines Module**.
5. Change the value to **Yes**.
6. Search **Product Module** Name.
7. Change the value to the name of your project.
8. In class, add the following: **#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"**

Hope this will work. let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Hi, Akshay, thank you for your answer. I've already followed all these steps, and everything works perfectly in the same xcodeproject. However, I don't know what to do so I can use this module in a different xcodeproject (but in a same xcworkspace). If I try to import  #import "YourProjectName-Swift.h", it is not recognized.